# Timer not working when Task is passed as parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, task

I'm trying to improve some code and want a more generic implementation of creating timers that run async. In the situation below MethodA is working as expected and writes to console every 4 seconds. I'd expect MethodB to work too, but somehow it only executes one time.

```
public async Task InitTimers()
{
    MethodA(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
    MethodB(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4), ExecTimer());
}

private async Task MethodA(TimeSpan refreshTime)
{
    var aTimer = new Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => ExecTimer().ConfigureAwait(false);
    aTimer.Interval = refreshTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    // Immediately trigger first time
    ExecTimer().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task MethodB(TimeSpan refreshTime, Task task)
{
    var aTimer = new Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    aTimer.Interval = refreshTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

    // Immediately trigger first time
    task.ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task ExecTimer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

Any idea what causes MethodB to only run once?

Comment: Why don't you use `Task.Delay` ? Anyway, a timer has to exist in order to execute anything periodically. The contents of variables are discarded as soon as you exit their context. Use a field instead

Comment: Furthermore, you can't "reexecute" a task. You don't execute it by awaiting it either or calling `ConfigureAwait` on it. The task is a *promise* that an already started operation will finish in the future. `ExecTimer` has already finished by the time it returls an already completed task. In both cases the timer doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by "generic implementation of creating timers that run async" and what it is you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a web service that needs to execute several background tasks on different intervals. When the webservice starts I want to initialize all timers to start running tasks. My current implementation works (methodA), but there is a lot of code duplication. Instead of making a MethodA variant for each background task I want to have a more generic timer method where I can pass the method as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Timer`s are getting disposed when they fall out of scope once the methods `MethodA`/`MethodB` complete. You'd need to create them outside the `Task`s or otherwise keep the `Task` running and the `Timer` in scope